# How can I update UI in Flutter without having to pop and push InsideFolder?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

in insideFolder it only updated when i pop and push the InsideFolder but i want to update anyTime
the _myList[0]['urlProgress'], updated
but it only show me the update when i pop and push

```
   Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => InsideFolder(
          progress: _myList[0]['urlProgress'],
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
```

can i use the inside folder another way like i dont want to push it i want to transfer the data

Comment: You need to create Stream of progress and then pass this Stream object to the InsideFolder and use StreamBuilder Widget to access this stream data. So whenever you update progress it will automatically reflect on InsideFolder screen.